# How to "properly" set boot options

Tags: systemd-boot

What is the correct way to set boot options with `systemd-boot`?

I currently add  them to the `options` line in the `current.conf` file at `/boot/efi/loader/entries/`, but this gets overwritten with any kernel update. Is there a way to set the options in a way that they persist across kernel updates?

Comment: You can either edit the `options` line in `/boot/efi/loader/entries/<entry>.conf` or you can set the `.cmdline` string in the EFI image, see https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd-boot#Preparing_a_unified_kernel_image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the answer thanks to user mmstick over at Reddit. Basically, use [`kernelstub`](https://github.com/isantop/kernelstub) provided by System76.

Instructions are [here](https://support.system76.com/articles/kernelstub/), the gist is to run

```bsh
sudo kernelstub -o "<option 1> <option 2>"
```

For example, to set both `quiet` and `splash` options, run

```bsh
sudo kernelstub -o "quiet splash"
```